# Mail Connection Doctor still attempting to access deleted Mail accounts

Tags: mail.app, email, accounts

I was testing some email servers and added several email accounts to my Mac. I deleted these accounts afterwards.

Now I have only three base accounts in `System Preferences > Internet Accounts`: Facebook, Twitter and iCloud.

[image: System Preference Internet Accounts]

However, **Mail Connection Doctor** (`Window > Connection Doctor`) still attempts to access the deleted accounts; if one of them has invalid credentials or settings it reports "Mail can't connect to the account."

[image: Connection Doctor]

Where these accounts are stored and can I permanently remove them so the Mail Connection Doctor doesn't try to connect?

Answer (score 2):

These accounts are stored in **Keychain Access** application and in servers list. To remove these accounts permanently, do following:

1. Open (Mail > Preferences > Accounts)
2. Select "Edit SMTP server list" from "Outgoing Mail Server" menu

[image]

3. Edit server list

Then remove accounts from **Keychain Access**:

1. Close **Mail**
2. Open **Keychain Access**
3. Select "login" in `Keychains` section
4. Select "Passwords" in `Category` section
5. Type deleted account name in Search field

There should appear several records, but you need only `com.apple.account.SMTP.xxx` and/or `com.apple.account.IMAP.xxx` entries with "application password" in Kind column.

[image]

Select and delete them. Open **Mail** and check Connection Doctor. There must remain only existing accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions on this and found the items to delete but still had the request for password on deleted account.
went back to the beginning and found that one of my new accounts(google)
for some reason was using the deleted accounts(btinternet) outgoing server.
I deleted (google) and reinstated it and all is now working.
thanks for the blog.